# How to use nginx with docker as a reverse proxy

Tags: django, nginx, proxy, docker

I have a django app and running it with gunicorn on localhost:8000
I have configs for nginx to use it as a reverse proxy.

```
    upstream django {
 #  fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
 #  to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
 #  single worker for timing out).

  server localhost:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

I know how to expose 80 port and run nginx in container, but I don't understand how to connect gunicorn running on localhost and nginx in container.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to utilize the IP of the bridge created by docker.  There is a good article on Docker explaining this:
https://docs.docker.com/v1.6/articles/networking/

> When Docker starts, it creates a virtual interface named docker0 on
>   the host machine. It randomly chooses an address and subnet from the
>   private range defined by RFC 1918 that are not in use on the host
>   machine, and assigns it to docker0.

If we take a look at the IP address assigned to docker0 (`sudo ip addr show docker0`) we could use this as the IP address to communicate with the host from within a docker container.

```
    upstream django {
 #  fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
 #  to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
 #  single worker for timing out).

  server IP_OF_DOCKER0:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}
```

I haven't tested the above but I believe it should work.  If not you may need to bind gunicorn to the docker0 IP as well.

This answer has some good insight into this process as well...
[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

Comment: you can also use the service name
```{
server app1:8000 fail_timeout=0; 
}```

Answer (score 0):

A better approach might be "dokerize" the django application too, build a
network between the dokerized nginx and the dockerized django application
then expose the http port from the dockerized nginx to all interfaces.

Here is a good [post](https://realpython.com/blog/python/django-development-with-docker-compose-and-machine/) about this, maybe you can take some hints from it :)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.